# How can I limit a list of node tokens to only a particular node type?

Tags: 7, tokens

We have many content types and fields, and the "Edit Node Type" page is taking about 30 seconds to load.  The culprit appears to be a module that lists all of the available "node" tokens, using this code:

```
$form['modulename']['token_help'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'token_tree',
  '#token_types' => array('node'),
);
```

'#token_types' => array('node') gives Node tokens for every content type, even though the form will only pertain to the one Content Type.

Is there a way to limit the token tree to display only node tokens pertaining to a specific content type (without using [Token Tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) module)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll just answer this as a "No".  [Token Tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) is what I needed to use to prevent long page loads (30 seconds at times...)

Comment: See also [A large amount of Tokens slows down everything - Placeholder Tokens](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11397/a-large-amount-of-tokens-slows-down-everything-placeholder-tokens/11567#11567) and [Token's available “Replacement patterns” nested table should only be displayed on-demand](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50605/tokens-available-replacement-patterns-nested-table-should-only-be-displayed-o/50678#50678)