# Token's available "Replacement patterns" nested table should only be displayed on-demand

Tags: 7, tokens

The [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module provides hooks to other modules to serve their own tokens. Multiple modules that support Token integration can generate a really huge nested table tree when displaying the available tokens in the field settings:

[image: Token Replacement Patters]

This can lead to out-of-memory issues in Views settings or regular field settings:

[image: Token Views fields - field settings + out of memory]

[image: Token nested tables - field settings + out of memory]

Earlier I created an issue related to this problem: http://drupal.org/node/1836264. Until a possible solution comes there (e.g. a patch), I would like to solve it my own (it doesn't matter if I temporarily have to "hack" Token's core): **I would only like to load this table with the available tokens "on-demand" with AJAX or any other possible solution**.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I agree, this is totally nasty. A form that includes the entire token tree can add tens of thousands of lines of markup to the html output of the page. Check out http://drupal.org/node/1684984 and http://drupal.org/node/1229568.

Comment: @CharlieS: thanks for the linked issues, these are really helpful! :)

Comment: @CharlieS: When reading the issues, I found [Token tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) module, with which you can set a depth limit for the token tree - it seems like it solves my problem, no more out of memory issues when setting the depth limit to `2`. Could you please post these issues and the link to this module as a separate answer? I would accept yours then. :) (I'm just looking for a temporary solution, until things mentioned in [Token UI 2.0 issue](http://drupal.org/node/1229568) get fixed somehow.) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default token tree can contain many thousands of lines of HTML, and the corresponding Javascript listeners and functionality can totally break things memory wise (or just give you a darn laggy experience). Plus it can confuse the heck out of site administrators.

These issues refer to current developments for loading the token tree 'on demand' or via a popup:

- http://drupal.org/node/1684984
- http://drupal.org/node/1229568

And OP pointed out in his comments, the [Token tweaks](http://drupal.org/project/token_tweaks) module lets you set a depth limit for the token tree, which seems to have solved his memory problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) There's another ongoing issue thread since then: http://drupal.org/node/1842738. I hope there will be a real solution soon (not just limiting the available tokens with setting the depth). :) +1 and accepted.